# Excel 2010 - VLookup, Search and Match are doing things beyond my imagination

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, search, vlookup

I have two worksheets, one containing a list of e-mail addresses and information, the other containing e-mail addresses that should be blacklisted. To remove the blacklisted e-mail addresses I thought it would be handy to add a column in the first worksheet which indicates whether or not the e-mail address in that row can be found in the blacklist worksheet.

I tried using `VLookup`, `Match` and `Search` but none are giving what I want...

**What am I doing wrong here?**

## @Peter: Using `IF` and `ISERROR` still doesn't work...

[image]

[image]

Vlookup second row: `=VLOOKUP(A2;Blacklist!A:B;2)`

Match second row: `=MATCH(A2;Blacklist!A:B)`

Search second row: `=SEARCH(A2;Blacklist!A:B)`

**Worksheet**
[image]

**Blacklist**
[image: Blacklist]

**@Peter Albert: adding `0` parameter**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting "weird" results with your `VLOOKUP` formula because in your source data range (`Blacklist!A:B`), the values you're trying to retrieve are located to the left of the values you're trying to look up.

To fix this:

1. Switch the **Source** & **Pattern** columns in the **Blacklist** worksheet, like so:

   [image]
2. Don't forget to add VLOOKUP's 4th parameter. Your formula should be:

   `=VLOOKUP(A2,Blacklist!A:B,2,FALSE)`

If your ultimate goal is just to determine which email addresses are in the blacklist, you an use this formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(Blacklist!B:B,A2), "Blacklisted", "Not Blacklisted")
```

Where `Blacklist!B:B` is the column that contains the blacklisted email address

Answer (score 2):

VLOOKUP and MATCH have another parameter, that is either TRUE or FALSE. TRUE is the default and results in wrong results if the data to be searched is not sorted! Therefore, simply add FALSE (or 0 as a short form) to your formulas and it'll work!

for your case, I'd use the MATCH function to determine if there is any match. Match return #N/A if it can't find a match or the number where it matches - so combining it with ISERROR will give you the best result:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2;Blacklist!B:B;0));"Not blacklisted";"Blacklisted!")
```

Comment: This still doesn't work... I've attached screenshots

Comment: @ropstah: See the updated answer!

Comment: Call me stupid, but it just doesn't find the value... All come up as "Not blacklisted". How is this possible?

Comment: I've attached new screenshots... everything is exactly as you specify...

Comment: did you copy the formula? I changed `A:B` to `B:B` (see Kaze's answer), so make sure that this is used. if that does not work, check if the email addresses in the Blacklist sheet have some spaces at the end.

Comment: Hi Peter, the update did solve the problem, however since Kaze gave this solution I had to award him the answer. Thanks!